# Two Questions about Python Dictionaries in Maya

Tags: python, dictionary, scripting, maya

Thanks for taking a moment to read this! So, my first issue is that I'm trying to create a function, "selectionData()", to get an object's translate, rotate, and scale values and then return them as a dictionary, but find myself struggling a bit. Using the code listed below, all I keep getting is the object's name. How can I modify it to get its translate, rotate, and scale values to return as a dictionary?

My second issue is that I'm trying to create a function, "setData(data)", that takes as input the aforementioned dictionary built with selectionData() and restores the data in the dictionary to the selected objects. How do I do that?

My apologies if either of these questions are foolish, but thank you for your time, regardless! Cheers!

Current code is listed below:

```
from maya import cmds

sel = cmds.ls(sl = 1)
meshes =[]
for s in sel :
    shape = cmds.listRelatives(s , shapes = 1 ) 
    if shape :
        if cmds.nodeType(shape[0]) == "mesh" :
            meshes.append(s )

meshData = {}            
for m in meshes :
    pos = cmds.xform ( m , q =1 , ws = 1 , t = 1)
    rot = cmds.xform( m , q =1  , ws = 1 , rotation =  1 )
    scl = cmds.getAttr ( m  + '.s' )[0]

    currentDict = {
                    "pos" : pos ,
                    "rot" : rot ,
                    "scl" : scl ,

                    }

    meshData[m] = currentDict

def selectionData( selectionDict):


    for k in selectionDict :
        print k

selectionData(meshData)
```

Comment: I got an error with the last print statement. Should it be `print(selectionDict[k])` ?

Comment: is it on purpose that you are nesting dictionaries ? selectionDict should be used like this in your example : for k in selectionDict.keys() : ///// print( selectionDict[k]['pos'] ) #### where k will be the mesh name

Comment: Oof, thanks for the save! Any chance you might also know how to get the translate, rotation, and scale values to return as a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to list all the objects with transforms you can use this command:

```
cmds.ls(selection=True, transforms=True, dagObjects=True)
```

If you want to read/write the transforms, you don't need to get the translation, then rotation and scale separately. You can read the composite transformation matrix like this:

```
xform_matrix = cmds.xform(source_object, query=True, matrix=True)
```

You'll get a list of 16 float numbers that are ready to be applied to other objects:

```
cmds.xform(destination_object, matrix=xform_matrix)
```

I am not sure how do you want to map the transforms from one set of selected objects to another set. If you describe, I'll be able to post the complete code.

The following script will collect the composite transformation matrix of all selected objects in the dictionary with long object names as the keys:

```
selected_objects_matrix = {}
for current_object in cmds.ls(selection=True, transforms=True, dagObjects=True):
    selected_objects_matrix[cmds.ls(current_object, long=True)] = cmds.xform(
        current_object,
        query=True,
        matrix=True)
```

Then if you move/rotate/scale the objects in Maya, you can revert like that:

```
for current_object in selected_objects_matrix:
    cmds.xform(
        current_object,
        matrix=selected_objects_matrix[current_object])
```

Answer (score 0):

you really just want to do what you have in reverse
setting the `q=1` sets the command into `query mode`.
removing this flag defaults the command to `edit mode`

`getAttr` and `setAttr` are their respective commands, however you need to be aware of the data that youre setting. even though youre grabbing the `s` attribute above youre making that only grab the `x` value so when you set it you need to specify `sx`

```
cmds.xform ( m , ws = 1 , t = posValues)
cmds.xform( m , ws = 1 , rotation = rotValues )
cmds.setAttr ( m  + '.sx', scaleValue) # sx because you are only grabbing the X Value
```